# Ищу библиотеку для работы с текстом (для создания текстового редактора)

Tags: c#, winforms, поиск-библиотек

Существует ли какая-нибудь библиотека для работы с текстом, то есть для создания текстового редактора?

Подразумевается работа с отображением текста. Как он будет выглядеть. Подсветка синтаксиса. Выделение слова при двойном клике на слово. Возможность писать текст в любом месте текстового документа, а не только с новой строчки. Подскажите все что знаете и платное.

Comment: [Richedit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: TextBox в режимеMultyLine сам по себе готовый редактор, только кнопки на интерфейс добавить нужные. RichTextBox - аналогично. Или вы хотите редактор уровня Word? Такое тоже есть, но за деньги, если нет желания копаться в OpenXML и самостоятельно строить отображение документа. Слишком общий у вас вопрос однако.

Comment: Подразумевается работа с отображением текста. Как он будет выглядеть. Подсветка синтаксиса. Выделение слова при двойном клике на слово. Возможность писать текст в любом месте текстового документа, а не только с новой строчки. Подскажите все что знаете и платное.

Comment: [Fast Colored TextBox](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/161871/Fast-Colored-TextBox-for-syntax-highlighting).

Answer (score 2):

Если текста не очень много, но нужно полноценное форматирование, рекомендую компонент RichEdit Control от [DevExpress](https://www.devexpress.com/products/net/controls/winforms/rich_editor/)

[image: RichEdit]

Он есть и под WinForms и под WPF.

Готового качественного и простого компонента для создания текстового редактора без форматирования (типа Sublime и Visual Studio Code) я не встречал. Подозреваю что такое проще написать самому.

Answer (score 1):

Для работы с текстом, а именно:

> Подразумевается работа с отображением текста. Как он будет выглядеть.
>   Подсветка синтаксиса. Выделение слова при двойном клике на слово.
>   Возможность писать текст в любом месте текстового документа, а не
>   только с новой строчки

неплохо подойдёт `AvalonEdit`. Вот ссылки на разные источники:

1. GitHub - https://github.com/icsharpcode/AvalonEdit
2. Документация - http://avalonedit.net/documentation/
3. Разбор функций и возможностей - https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42490/Using-AvalonEdit-WPF-Text-Editor

Подключается к проекту как nuget пакет: https://www.nuget.org/packages/AvalonEdit

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос по сути не корректен. Что подразумевается под "работой с текстом"? Сохранение, запись, чтение, встроено в среду. 
Выделение/вырезание встроено в контролы. 
Подсветка синтаксиса и оформление? https://github.com/jacobslusser/ScintillaNET (на данной библиотеке Notepad++ работает).

Comment: Подразумевается работа с отображением текста. Как он будет выглядеть. Подсветка синтаксиса. Выделение слова при двойном клике на слово. Возможность писать текст в любом месте текстового документа, а не только с новой строчки.